# How can I send iPhone to iPhone messages rather than SMS messages?

Tags: ios, messages, sms

My friend has an iPhone the same as mine, but when we message each other they get sent as SMS messages not iPhone to iPhone messages? This of course costs us more money through our telephone provider.

Comment: Do you both have an iCloud account?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use iMessage or another messaging service like WhatsApp etc.